# R: operate over subset of columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns

I'm trying to implement a data.table for my relatively large datasets and I can't figure out how to operate a function over multiple columns in the same row.  Specifically, I want to create a new column that contains a specifically-formatted tally of the values (i.e., a histogram) in a subset of columns. It is kind of like table() but that also includes 0 entries and is sorted--so, if you know of a better/faster method I'd appreciate that too!

Simplified test case:

```
DF<-data.frame("A"=c("a","d","a"),"B"=c("b","a","a"),"C"=c("c","a","a"),"D"=c("a","b","c"),"E"=c("a","a","c"))
DT<-as.data.table(DF)
> DT
   A B C D E
1: a b c a a
2: d a a b a
3: a a a c c
```

my klunky histogram function:

```
histo<-function(vec){
                     foo<-c("a"=0,"b"=0,"c"=0,"d"=0)
                     for(i in vec){foo[i]=foo[i]+1}
                     return(foo)}
>histo(unname(unlist(DF[1,])))
a b c d
3 1 1 0
>histo(unname(unlist(DF[2,])))
a b c d
3 1 0 1
>histo(unname(unlist(DF[3,])))
a b c d
3 0 2 0
```

pseduocode of desired function and output

```
>DT[,his:=some_func_with_histo(A:E)]
>DT
   A B C D E his
1: a b c a a (3,1,1,0)
2: d a a b a (3,1,0,1)
3: a a a c c (3,0,2,0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the preferred place to explain my choice of answers is, so I'm doing it here. Both Frank and @Christoph_J had good solutions. I updated Frank's with the tweaks from Christoph_J to output one column and use a subset of columns with .SDcol. I then timed both of them on part of my actual data (a DT with 30,000 rows where 8 of 66 columns are to be histogrammed) using system.time (seems OK since I'm only doing one replicate). Frank's solution was 58.4 sec and Christoph_J's solution was 145.0 sec. So unless there's any dramatic updates I'll be using Frank's solution. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the answer that I accepted after @noah modified his from data.frame to data.table.  At 6.9 sec I am surprised at how much faster it is than Frank's (58.4 sec) and Chrstoph_J's (145 sec), which (to my eye) both seem to utilize the `data.table` more naturally.  The speed increase, however, is more important so it's the winner.  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.table(DF)
df$hist <- unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    list(      
        sapply(letters[1:4], function(d) {
            b <- sum(!is.na(grep(d,x)))
            assign(d, b)
        }))
}), recursive=FALSE)
```

Your df$hist column is a list, with each value named:

```
> df
   A B C D E    hist
1: a b c a a 3,1,2,0
2: d a a b a 3,1,1,1
3: a a a c c 3,0,3,0

> df$hist
[[1]]
a b c d 
3 1 2 0 

[[2]]
a b c d 
3 1 1 1 

[[3]]
a b c d 
3 0 3 0
```

Comment: impressive. I appreciate that you've included the histo in it's own column (unlike other responses). I'm still trying to wrap my head around what you're doing, but I think I'm going to go with one of the data.table answers since my real data is huge (i.e., genomic) and the data.table saves me lots of time in other aspects.

Comment: yeah you're right.  how hard is it to include the 0 values in the histogram and order it?  as-is your code is actually fastest at 15.3 sec, but (perhaps foolishly) I'd like the hist column to be formatted as specified. also, to use your solution on just columns A,B,E I guess I'd just have to change to `apply(df[,list(A,B,E)...`?  it may not be worth your time since even if you modified the histo feature but were faster by only ~10% of Frank's answer I'd probably still choose his as it is easier for me to understand.  thanks.

Comment: yeah, a sorted list of the counts for each letter including zero entries.  see the 'his' column in my mock output of the original question for something like I was hoping for.

Comment: wow, very fast and the fact that it's a `data.table` seems irrelevant, which surprises me...

Comment: Yeah, strange that it's fast. As @mnel said, `apply` should be slow (because it converts to a matrix). Anyway, you might get a further speed-up by using `data.table` syntax to create the column: `dt[,hist:=...]` instead of `dt$hist <- ...`. I'm not really sure about that, though. I have no idea how that `assign` step is working, but um, +1 for speed.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Answer has been updated to to OP's request and mnel's comment**

OK, how do you like that solution:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(A=c("a","d","a"),
                 B=c("b","a","a"),
                 C=c("c","a","a"),
                 D=c("a","b","c"),
                 E=c("a","a","c"))

fun <- function(vec, char) {
  sum(vec==char)
}

DT[, Vec_Nr:= paste(Vectorize(fun, 'char')(.SD, letters[1:4]), collapse=","),
   by=1:nrow(DT),
   .SDcols=LETTERS[1:5]]
   A B C D E  Vec_Nr
1: a b c a a 3,1,1,0
2: d a a b a 3,1,0,1
3: a a a c c 3,0,2,0
```

I basically split up your problem into several steps:

First, I define a function `fun` that gives me the number of occurrences for one character. To see how
that function works, just call

```
fun(c("a", "a", "b"), "b")
[1] 1
```

Next, I vectorize this function because you don't want to know that for only one character "b", but for many. To pass a vector of arguments to a function,
use `Vectorize`. To see how that works, just type

```
Vectorize(fun, "char")(c("a", "a", "b"), c("a", "b"))
a b 
2 1
```

Next, I collapse the results into one string and save that as a new column. Note that I deliberatly used the `letters` and `LETTERS` here to show you how make this more dynamic.

Comment: I like the way you used `sum(vec==char)` and then vectorized it.  I'll definitely put that in my bag of tricks for later use.  As far as the eventual application of this problem to a very large dataset (genomic scale), I wonder if cbind will scale to many (tens of) millions of rows?  Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `apply` or `t` on data.frames or data.tables. This will coerce to matrix.

Comment: EDIT: seems like I was writing this while you updated yours. my last two questions to @Frank about single-column and .SDcols are relevant here now too.

Comment: @mnel Thanks for the hint, I adjusted accordingly. Although I don't quite see the problem, so it would be great if you could elaborate. It does coerce to matrix, but doesn't it coerce back when I use it in a `data.table`. At least the output looked fine.

Comment: @jfb I actually thought it was a feature of my solution that it adds additional columns instead of a vector. Because you can't really do any analysis on a string vector...anyways, I have updated my answer to conform to your request. Also, I added a more dynamic solution with `.SDcols`.

Comment: It coerces to matrix -- this is slow and not memory efficient. data.table is for memory efficiency and time efficiency.

Comment: @Christoph_J thanks for both extra solutions.  As I get better with this, perhaps I'll revert back to the multi-column approach, but for now a single column is easier since I'm going to be implementing this solution on ~5 sets of columns, each with 5 possible factors so that is 25 extra columns if I add each one versus only 5 if I treat them as a vector. Since the real dataset starts off ~60 columns 65 seems easier to handle than 85.  anyway that's my rationale...

Comment: @Christoph_J I explained in a comment to the original question why I chose Frank's solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (also see below): Provided you first convert column classes to character, e.g., with `DT <- DT[,lapply(.SD,as.character)]`...

By using `factor`, you can convert `vec` and pass the values (a,b,c,d) in one step:

```
histo2 <- function(x) table(factor(x,levels=letters[1:4]))
```

Then you can iterate over rows by passing `by=1:nrow(DT)`.

```
DT[,as.list(histo2(.SD)),by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

This gives...

```
   nrow a b c d
1:    1 3 1 1 0
2:    2 3 1 0 1
3:    3 3 0 2 0
```

Also, this iterates over columns. This works because `.SD` is a special variable holding the subset of data associated with the call to `by`. In this case, that subset is the `data.table` consisting of one of the rows. `histo2(DT[1])` works the same way.

EDIT (responding to OP's comment): Oh, sorry, I instinctively replaced your first line with

```
DF<-data.frame("A"=c("a","d","a"),"B"=c("b","a","a"),"C"=c("c","a","a"),"D"=c("a","b","c"),"E"=c("a","a","c")
,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

since I dislike using factors except when making tables. If you do not want to convert your factor columns to character columns in this way, this will work:

```
histo3 <- function(x) table(factor(sapply(x,as.character),levels=letters[1:4]))
```

To put the output into a single column, you use `:=` as you suggested...

```
DT[,hist:=list(list(histo3(.SD))),by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

The `list(list())` part is key; I always figure this out by trial-and-error. Now DT looks like this:

```
   A B C D E    hist
1: a b c a a 3,1,1,0
2: d a a b a 3,1,0,1
3: a a a c c 3,0,2,0
```

You might find that it's a pain to access the information directly from your new column. For example, to access the "a" column of the "histogram", I think the fastest route is...

```
DT[,hist[[1]][["a"]],by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

My initial suggestion created an auxiliary data.table with just the counts. I think it's cleaner to do whatever you want to do with the counts in that data.table and then `cbind` it back. If you choose to store it in a column, you can always create the auxiliary data.table later with

```
DT[,as.list(hist[[1]]),by=1:nrow(DT)]
```

You are correct about using `.SDcols`. For your example, ...

```
cols = c("A","C")
histname = paste(c("hist",cols),collapse="")
DT[,(histname):=list(list(histo3(.SD))),by=1:nrow(DT),.SDcols=cols]
```

This gives

```
   A B C D E    hist  histAC
1: a b c a a 3,1,1,0 1,0,1,0
2: d a a b a 3,1,0,1 1,0,0,1
3: a a a c c 3,0,2,0 2,0,0,0
```

Comment: your answer seems the most concise and very close; however when I implement it, I get all 0's for my histo columns. same when I try: `histo2(DT[1])`. Instead, I have to modify it: `histo2(unname(unlist(DT[1])))`. Am I missing something? Also, how hard would it be to compress the 4 new columns into one containing a vector? that way I could use `:=` notation to make it a single new column (I think?).  my real data set has ~60 columns so adding so many more for each histo seems unwieldy. Also, can I use `.SDcols=COLS` where COLS=c("A","C") (for example) to subset the columns? thanks.